# How to list all packages and repositories for re-installation

Tags: apt, package-management, ssd, repository

I am configuring a new machine that will be an environment clone of the old machine, both X86-64 processors but different hardware (thus a direct copy of the "old" SSD would not work as the Ubuntu installer evidently scans the hardware for the "correct" drivers, etc).  I have already copied /home from the old machine to the new machine -- everything "works" except that most applications are missing.  Rather than manually installing each one from the name appearing on the desktop, etc, is there a means to generate from the old machine (also 22.04.2 current) a list of the installed repositories and applications such that this would be acceptable as input to, say, `apt`?  As I removed the SSD from the old machine and using a SSD to USB adapter mounted the old SSD onto the new machine (hence using `sudo cp -pra` with renaming and then `sudo mv` did the above full copy of `home`) are there directories, files, etc, on the old SSD that would contain the needed information to "automate" the apt install procedure?  The Ask Ubuntu robot produced some answers from the year 2014, but I fear that enough has changed that I need to address this topic for the current 22.04.2 .  Is there is an `apt` configuration directory/directory tree that contains the information and then a specific `apt` "directive/s" that would force a re-reading of that configuration to make the current set of installed repositories and applications the same as on the old machine, both being 22.04.2 LTS current?

Comment: `dpkg --get-selections` / `dpkg --set-selections` may be what you are looking for - see for example [How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)

Comment: dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall > backup.txt This command saves package names in the backup.txt file.